# MCollective server cannot connect to ActiveMQ broker

Tags: ssl, puppet, activemq, mcollective

I've been trying all do to set up MCollective on my puppet cluster.  No matter what I do, I can't seem to get the MCollective server to connect.  The MCollective server(s) are running mostly on Ubnutu Xenial.  The ActiveMQ broker (5.14.3) is running on Debian Stretch.  I'm running puppet 4.x on all nodes. I've used every transport connector I can thing if, and they all fail to connect.  Let me dump some log files at you.

In mcollective.log I'm getting `Connection reset by peer`:

```
I, [2017-01-27T15:43:59.869501 #18729]  INFO -- : activemq.rb:139:in `on_ssl_connecting' Establishing SSL session with stomp+ssl://mcollective@broker.example.com:61614
E, [2017-01-27T15:44:00.070995 #18729] ERROR -- : activemq.rb:149:in `on_ssl_connectfail' SSL session creation with stomp+ssl://mcollective@broker.example.com:61614 failed: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect
I, [2017-01-27T15:44:00.071371 #18729]  INFO -- : activemq.rb:129:in `on_connectfail' TCP Connection to stomp+ssl://mcollective@broker.example.com:61614 failed on attempt 24
```

Oddly enough, in the ActiveMQ log, I also seem to be getting `Connection reset by peer`:

```
ERROR | Could not accept connection from null : {}
java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.nio.NIOSSLTransport.initializeStreams(NIOSSLTransport.java:188)[activemq-client.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompNIOSSLTransport.initializeStreams(StompNIOSSLTransport.java:57)[activemq-stomp.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.connect(TcpTransport.java:543)[activemq-client.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.nio.NIOTransport.doStart(NIOTransport.java:174)[activemq-client.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.nio.NIOSSLTransport.doStart(NIOSSLTransport.java:462)[activemq-client.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:55)[activemq-client.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:64)[activemq-client.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.stomp.StompTransportFilter.start(StompTransportFilter.java:65)[activemq-stomp.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.start(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:169)[activemq-client.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.start(TransportFilter.java:64)[activemq-client.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.start(TransportConnection.java:1072)[activemq-broker.jar:]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector$1$1.run(TransportConnector.java:218)[activemq-broker.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_111]
```

So they're both resetting the connection.  Huh.  Before you ask, no: there are no iptables rules, and yes: there is a route between the two nodes.  Let's take a peak at `lsof -i` just to be sure and then I'll throw some config files at you.

```
java    20833 activemq   84u  IPv6  53552      0t0  TCP *:61614 (LISTEN)
```

activemq.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE activemq [
  <!ENTITY keyStores SYSTEM "keyStores.xml">
]>
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>

    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
            useJmx="false"
            brokerName="broker"
            dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data">

      <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${activemq.base}/data/kahadb"/>
      </persistenceAdapter>

      <sslContext>
        &keyStores;
      </sslContext>

      <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector
          name="stomp+nio"
          uri="stomp+nio+ssl://0.0.0.0:61614?needClientAuth=true&amp;transport.enabledProtocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"/>
      </transportConnectors>

      <plugins>
        <simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
          <users>
            <authenticationUser username="mcollective" password="password" groups="mcollective,everyone"/>
            <authenticationUser username="admin" password="password" groups="mcollective,admins,everyone"/>
          </users>
        </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
        <authorizationPlugin>
          <map>
            <authorizationMap>
              <authorizationEntries>
                <authorizationEntry queue=">" write="admins" read="admins" admin="admins" />
                <authorizationEntry topic=">" write="admins" read="admins" admin="admins" />
                <authorizationEntry topic="mcollective.>" write="mcollective" read="mcollective" admin="mcollective" />
                <authorizationEntry queue="mcollective.>" write="mcollective" read="mcollective" admin="mcollective" />
                <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="everyone" write="everyone" admin="everyone"/>
              </authorizationEntries>
            </authorizationMap>
          </map>
        </authorizationPlugin>
      </plugins>
    </broker>

</beans>
```

keyStores.xml:

```
<sslContext
    keyStore="/etc/activemq/keystore.jks"
    keyStorePassword="password"
    trustStore="/etc/activemq/truststore.jks"
    trustStorePassword="password" />
```

mcollective/server.cfg:

```
# /etc/mcollective/server.cfg

# ActiveMQ connector settings:
connector = activemq
direct_addressing = 1
plugin.activemq.pool.size = 1
plugin.activemq.pool.1.host = broker.example.com
plugin.activemq.pool.1.port = 61614
plugin.activemq.pool.1.user = mcollective
plugin.activemq.pool.1.password = password
plugin.activemq.pool.1.ssl = 1
plugin.activemq.pool.1.ssl.ca = /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem
plugin.activemq.pool.1.ssl.cert = /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/mail.example.com.pem
plugin.activemq.pool.1.ssl.key = /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/mail.example.com.pem
plugin.activemq.pool.1.ssl.fallback = 0

# SSL security plugin settings:
securityprovider = ssl
plugin.ssl_client_cert_dir = /etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/clients
plugin.ssl_server_private = /etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/server_private.pem
plugin.ssl_server_public = /etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/server_public.pem

# Facts, identity, and classes:
identity = mail.example.com
factsource = yaml
plugin.yaml = /etc/puppetlabs/mcollective/facts.yaml
classesfile = /var/lib/puppet/state/classes.txt

# No additional subcollectives:
collectives = mcollective
main_collective = mcollective

# Registration:
# We don't configure a listener, and only send these messages to keep the
# Stomp connection alive. This will use the default "agentlist" registration
# plugin.
registerinterval = 600

# Auditing (optional):
# If you turn this on, you must arrange to rotate the log file it creates.
rpcaudit = 1
rpcauditprovider = logfile
plugin.rpcaudit.logfile = /var/log/mcollective-audit.log

# Authorization:
# If you turn this on now, you won't be able to issue most MCollective
# commands, although `mco ping` will work. You should deploy the
# ActionPolicy plugin before uncommenting this; see "Deploy Plugins" below.

# rpcauthorization = 1
# rpcauthprovider = action_policy
# plugin.actionpolicy.allow_unconfigured = 1

# Logging:
logger_type = file
loglevel = debug
logfile = /var/log/mcollective.log
keeplogs = 5
max_log_size = 2097152
logfacility = user

# Platform defaults:
# These settings differ based on platform; the default config file created by
# the package should include correct values. If you are managing settings as
# resources, you can ignore them, but with a template you'll have to account
# for the differences.
libdir = /usr/share/mcollective/plugins
daemonize = 1
```

The keys/certs in keystore.jks and truststore.jks are correct and so is the password.  The shared keys and certs are also available.  So lets try connecting with `openssl`:

```
root@mail:/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl# openssl s_client -connect broker.example.com:61614 -CAfile certs/ca.pem -cert certs/mail.example.com.pem -key private_keys/mail.example.com.pem
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 305 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1485554633
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I'm not exactly sure how to interpret this, maybe someone else knows.  Any new good guesses would be helpful, I'm stuck.